# EventHandler, event, delegate based programming in Python any example would appreciate?

Tags: python, events, delegates, function-pointers, event-handling

Basically I'm a C# developer,
I know the way C# does, EventHandler, delegate, even...

but whats the best way to implement it on Python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a function:

```
def do_work_and_notify(on_done):
    // do work
    on_done()

def send_email_on_completion():
    email_send('joe@example.com', 'you are done')

do_work_and_notify(send_email_on_completion)
```

Functions (and even methods) in python are first-class objects that can be tossed around like anything else in the language.

Comment: How to go about if let's say on_done function takes some number of arguments?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a lot like [Python Observer Pattern: Examples, Tips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904351/python-observer-pattern-examples-tips) which has lots of great answers. There's even an implementation of C#-like events in Python.