# Implementing a callback in Python - passing a callable reference to the current function

Tags: python, design-patterns, functional-programming, callback, observer-pattern

I want to implement the `Observable` pattern in Python for a couple of workers, and came across this helpful snippet:

```
class Event(object):
    pass

class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = []
    def subscribe(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)
    def fire(self, **attrs):
        e = Event()
        e.source = self
        for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
            setattr(e, k, v)
        for fn in self.callbacks:
            fn(e)
```

Source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904351/python-observer-pattern-examples-tips)

As i understand it, in order to `subscribe`, I would need to pass a callback to the function that is going to be called on `fire`. If the calling function was a `class` method, presumably I could have used `self`, but in the absence of this - how could I directly get a callback that can be useful for the `self.callbacks.append(callback)` bit?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Any defined function can be passed by simply using its name, without adding the `()` on the end that you would use to invoke it:

```
def my_callback_func(event):
    # do stuff

o = Observable()
o.subscribe(my_callback_func)
```

---

Other example usages:

```
class CallbackHandler(object):
    @staticmethod
    def static_handler(event):
        # do stuff

    def instance_handler(self, event):
        # do stuff

o = Observable()

# static methods are referenced as <class>.<method>
o.subscribe(CallbackHandler.static_handler)

c = CallbackHandler()
# instance methods are <class instance>.<method>
o.subscribe(c.instance_handler)

# You can even pass lambda functions
o.subscribe(lambda event: <<something involving event>>)
```

Comment: Missing `self` argument in the methods.

Comment: Whoops. Forgot it on the instance method. The static method doesn't get a `self`.

Comment: Great, thanks you very much - I was grappling with static in fact:)

Comment: @Amber, how would you make the call from the Observable method to the callback? Assume Observable stores the method in a 'callback' variable - what is the syntax of the call?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Amber's main answer above, this is a complete example of how two classes can be used to implement a callback from one to another.

I dummied this up to satisfy my own curiosity on whether it would work or not - particularly given that `register` only seems to be called with a function being passed, but now that I've seen this example work, the function must be passed with a context of the object to which it is attached.

```
class A():
    def register(self,fn):
        self.cb=fn
    
    def gimme(self,val):
        self.cb(val)

class B():
    def __init__(self, o):
        self.o = o
        self.o.register(self.callback)
    
    def callback(self,val):
        print(f"Got called with {val} !!")

    def go(self):
        self.o.gimme('test')

>>> a = A()
>>> b = B(a)
>>> b.go()
Got called with test !!
```