# Python control flow issue : function calls

Tags: python

Given below is the control flow of my python code:

```
from BB import B
def A(param):
    ...
    ...
    //This takes a while to complete execution
    ...
    B()
print something
A(param) //Function call
```

The problem here is that the function B is called before A can complete its execution. A creates and write to a file, while B reads from it and performs some operation. B being called after the completion of A is pretty important.

I tried this, but it dint solve the issue.

```
from BB import B
def A(param):
    ...
    ...
    //This takes a while to complete execution
    ...
print something
A(param) //Function call
B()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the callback concept? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689984/implementing-a-callback-in-python-passing-a-callable-reference-to-the-current

Comment: Did you possibly forget to close the file after A() has written to it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to make `A` a blocking call -- i.e. avoid returning until the process is done.  If it's writing to a file, you might consider the following:

```
import os

from time import sleep

def A(param):

    filepath = "/path/to/output/file"
    ... do stuff ...
    while not os.path.exists(filepath):
        sleep(5)
    B()
```

However, as @Joze comments, you might want to use a callback strategy just for general composition reasons.

Comment: Blocking call isn't helping, and along with that I get a Value Error due to some file opening/closing issue. I'm not able to figure out how and where to include the callback strategy.

Comment: @RowenaRavenclaw, it sounds like you have an issue with the part of your code that writes the file.  I would recommend sharing that snippet.

Comment: Thanks! The file is actually written by redirecting the output from the console. I then ssh to another server where I do something while the 'print' statements on the console get redirected to this file. In the other server where I ssh to, I read and write from  and to a few other files.

Comment: Then it sounds like your code is trying to access the file while it's being written to.  In this situation, you need a way to poll for the state of the file.  This is the annoying thing about relying on side effects from within your code.  Is there any way you can re-write your code to write the file using python rather than manipulating stdout?  Otherwise, if you know that there's a max on how long it takes to write to this file, then just sleep for that long.

Comment: I ssh to a server and run the script. So in order to capture the logs, I had to redirect the stdout. If I do any other file operation, it gets written to a file on the server that I ssh into...

Answer (score 0):

Brute forcing it, you could place a timer in before B() does some reading.
import time
time.sleep(5) # delays for 5 seconds

Or tweak the 5 seconds to be the shortest time you expect that will still work