# Possible to pass a function into a object's method as an argument, which can refer to that object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming, self, function-object

```
def my_func():
    stuff
    return something

my_object.my_method(my_func)
```

I want my_func to be able to refer to `my_object`. Essentially like deferred `self`, which means "whatever object I am in, refer to that"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **[`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)** module

```
import inspect

def my_func():
    stuff
    my_object = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals["self"]
    return something
```

However, I guess a simpler approach would be to pass the instance as argument, such as

```
def my_func():
    stuff
    return something

my_object.my_method(my_func, caller=my_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a [callback](http://code-maven.com/function-or-callback-in-python).

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689984/implementing-a-callback-in-python-passing-a-callable-reference-to-the-current) is a usage of callback in a design pattern.