# i want to exit my home() before login ()

Tags: python

I want to exit my `home()` before `login()`

```
def _home():
    def button_pressed():
        if admin:
            _admin_login()

        if pilot:
            _pilot_login()

    #creating button for admin user
    admin=tk.Button(home, text="Admin logIN", width=20,height=3, bd=0, highlightthicknes=0, command=button_pressed)
    admin.place(x=150, y=200)

    #configuring admin button
    admin.config(image=photoAdmin, width="200", height="240")

    #creating button for pilot log in
    pilot=tk.Button(home, text="Pilot LogIN", width=20, height=3, bd=0, command=button_pressed)
    pilot.place(x=400, y=200)

    #conguring pilot button
    pilot.config(image=photoPilot, width="200", height="240")
```

Comment: You can use a `return` statement to exit a function early as well as return a value from that function if you want. The default value of `return` if nothing is supplied is `None`.

Comment: where should i've to put exit(0) or return

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it already should.  When you create a new `Button` and assigning a function to `command` you're basically attaching a [`callback`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689984/implementing-a-callback-in-python-passing-a-callable-reference-to-the-current). Your `button_pressed` function will only run when the button is clicked in the GUI.