# Python observable implementation that supports multi-channel subscribers

Tags: python

In a twisted application I have a series of resource controller/manager classes that interact via the Observable pattern.  Generally most observers will subscribe to a specific channel (ex. "foo.bar.entity2") but there are a few cases where I'd like to know about all event in a specific channel (ex. "foo.*" ) so I wrote something like the following:

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    class SimplePubSub(object):

        def __init__(self):
            self.subjects = defaultdict(list)


        def subscribe(self, subject, callbackstr):
            """
                for brevity, callbackstr would be a valid Python function or bound method but here is just a string
            """
            self.subjects[subject].append(callbackstr)

        def fire(self, subject):
            """
                Again for brevity, fire would have *args, **kwargs or some other additional message arguments but not here            
            """

            if subject in self.subjects:
                print "Firing callback %s" % subject
                for callback in self.subjects[subject]:
                    print "callback %s" % callback



    pubSub = SimplePubSub()
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.bar', "foo.bar1")
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.foo', "foo.foo1")

    pubSub.subscribe('foo.ich.tier1', "foo.ich.tier3_1")
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.ich.tier2', "foo.ich.tier2_1")
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.ich.tier3', "foo.ich.tier2_1")

    #Find everything that starts with foo
    #say foo.bar is fired
    firedSubject = "foo.bar"
    pubSub.fire(firedSubject)
    #outputs 
    #>>Firing callback foo.bar
    #>>callback foo.bar1

    #but let's say I want to add a callback for everything undr foo.ich

    class GlobalPubSub(SimplePubSub):

        def __init__(self):
            self.globals = defaultdict(list)
            super(GlobalPubSub, self).__init__()


        def subscribe(self, subject, callback):
            if subject.find("*") > -1:
                #assumes global suscriptions would be like subject.foo.* and we want to catch all subject.foo's 
                self.globals[subject[:-2]].append(callback)
            else:
                super(GlobalPubSub, self).subscribe(subject, callback)

        def fire(self, subject):
            super(GlobalPubSub, self).fire(subject)
            if self.globals:
                for key in self.globals.iterkeys():
                    if subject.startswith(key):
                        for callback in self.globals[key]:
                            print "global callback says", callback

    print "Now with global subscriptions"
    print
    pubSub = GlobalPubSub()
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.bar', "foo.bar1")
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.foo', "foo.foo1")

    pubSub.subscribe('foo.ich.tier1', "foo.ich.tier3_1")
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.ich.tier2', "foo.ich.tier2_1")
    pubSub.subscribe('foo.ich.tier3', "foo.ich.tier2_1")
    pubSub.subscribe("foo.ich.*", "All the ichs, all the time!")

    #Find everything that starts with foo.ich
    firedSubject = "foo.ich.tier2"
    pubSub.fire(firedSubject)
    #outputs 
    #>>Firing callback foo.bar
    #>>callback foo.bar1
    #>>Now with global subscriptions
    #
    #>>Firing callback foo.ich.tier2
    #>>callback foo.ich.tier2_1
    #>>global callback says All the ichs, all the time!
```

Is this as good as it gets without resorting to some sort of exotic construct ( tries for example )?  I'm looking for an affirmation that I'm on the right track or a better alternative suggestion on a global subscription handler that's pure python ( no external libraries or services ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are on the right track to me. I was using [PyPubSub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/) with a wxPython app for a bit, and then ended up implementing my own "more simple" version that, at its root, looks very similar to what you've done here except with a few more bells and whistles that you'd probably end up implementing as you fill out your requirements.

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904351/python-observer-pattern-examples-tips) is also lot like what you have done as well.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python) goes into examples that are a bit different approach.

There are a number existing libraries besides [PyPubSub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/) out there, such as [pydispatch](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) and [blinker](http://discorporate.us/projects/Blinker/), that might be worth looking at for reference or ideas.