# Python observer/observable library

Tags: python, observer-pattern

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Observer Pattern: Examples, Tips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904351/python-observer-pattern-examples-tips)

Is there a specific library that implements the observer/observable(gof) pattern in Python? I'd use it to update a wxPython view from my model. Writing my own wouldn't be difficult, but I'm wondering if there's something specific for Python.

Comment: @glglgl thank you for the reference, I'll look into python's logging module. It seems to be able to do what I want, though the name doesn't suggest it :).