# How to wait for object to change state

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Inside my `async` handler I want to wait until task's state is changed. For now, I just check the state in an endless loop and wait. Here is an example, the `wait_until_done` function:

```
import asyncio


class LongTask:
    state = 'PENDING'

my_task = LongTask()


def done():
    my_task.state = 'DONE'

async def wait_until_done():
    while True:
        if my_task.state == 'PENDING':
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        else:
            break
    print("Finally, the task is done")


def main(loop, *args, **kwargs):
    asyncio.ensure_future(wait_until_done())
    loop.call_later(delay=5, callback=done)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
main(loop)
loop.run_forever()
```

Is there a better way for doing that?

Comment: Observer pattern is probably what you want to use. Make the object "observable" you then register a handler as an observer to your object so when the state change it will call what ever method you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904351/python-observer-pattern-examples-tips

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to avoid confusion: I guess you are not talking about [asyncio.Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task), but some variable state instead, right?

In this case you have [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future) and [synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#synchronization-primitives) that allows you to wait some thing changed asynchronously.

If you need to switch between two states, [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) is probably what you want. Here's little examle:

```
import asyncio


my_task = asyncio.Event()


def done():
    my_task.set()



async def wait_until_done():
    await my_task.wait()  # await until event would be .set()
    print("Finally, the task is done")


async def main():
    loop.call_later(delay=5, callback=done)
    await wait_until_done()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

**Upd:**

More complex example that keeps `LongTask` interface:

```
import asyncio



class LongTask:
    _event = asyncio.Event()

    @property
    def state(self):
        return 'PENDING' if not type(self)._event.is_set() else 'DONE'

    @state.setter
    def state(self, val):
        if val == 'PENDING':
            type(self)._event.clear()
        elif val == 'DONE':
            type(self)._event.set()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Bad state value.')

    async def is_done(self):
        return (await type(self)._event.wait())

my_task = LongTask()


def done():
    my_task.state = 'DONE'



async def wait_until_done():
    await my_task.is_done()
    print("Finally, the task is done")


async def main():
    loop.call_later(delay=5, callback=done)
    await wait_until_done()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Yes, the task is a regular object, not asyncio.Task. I thought about the Event(), but your solution is not suitable: long story short, I can not touch the `done` func, it should just change state of the task.

Comment: @SergeyBelash, I added another example that keeps `done` func unchanged.